# Hadoop - Image Input Format - JPEG to base64 conversion

Tags: java, image, hadoop

I'm relatively new to Hadoop and so far my only experience with it is the wordcount problem.

**What I'm trying to Accomplish:**
I'm trying to write a mapreduce job to convert images in JPEG format to base64 format. The images will all be kept in a single directory. I need to read the images from this directory and convert the image to base64 string in my mapper.
Then in my reducer I need to combine the base64 strings for all images and consolidate it all into one log/txt file.

**The problems I'm facing:**
I'm having a problem with the input format. Most examples on the net show only usage text input format. When writing a normal java program to convert image to base64, I used BufferedImage class. I would like to know if its possible define input formats for mapreduce so that I can work with images, and if so what all should be done.

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can think of, you have the following options:

1- Using HIPI (Hadoop Image Processing Interface), which provides many tools for image processing

2- Using 3rd-party Image input formats like ImageInputFormat

3- Using 3rd-party WholeFileInputFormat to read one whole image at a time, but it will be read as a whole file so you will need to parse it.

3- If all your images are of the same size in bytes, you can use FixedLengthInputFormat. Still, depending on your images there might be some need for parsing.

4- If none of these suit you, then you might want to read a bit about how to make your own input format that suits your purposes. You can find a good tutorial to do that either in the book Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, or [here](http://www.infoq.com/articles/HadoopInputFormat)

Good luck